# What's the best approach to store transactions in Neo4j?

Tags: transactions, neo4j, store

I'm newer in the graph world and today, while I was modeling some graphs to control account transactions, I had the following question: "What's the best approach to store transactions when we are talking about dates?"

I thought about two nodes, account and transactions, and the dates of transactions like property of node transaction.

I thought about two nodes, account and transactions, and the dates of transactions like property of the relationship.

And now, I'm thinking about one node for account, other for years, other for months, other for days and then other for transaction, like a tree.

Which(or What in case if we have another) one is the best for use in Neo4j? Which one have the best performace? When I'll have a 1 billion of transactions, which one will be best?

Thank's everyone!
Alain Oliveira

P.S.:sorry about my english.

Comment: Check out the GraphAware TimeTree plugin: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree#using-graphaware-timetree It's a plugin for Neo4j that can build a time-based index in the graph on demand. Even if you decide not to use the library their README has a good overview of the data model.

Comment: @AlainOliveira You need to define your use cases before you start designing a data model. What kinds of queries do you want to perform?

Comment: @cybersam I've a web application using MySQL. I'm trying to migrate the database to Neo4j, just for study and learn about graphs. In this case, my queries are about: What was the last transaction of an account? How many transactions an account had in the last month, or year? I know the questions but what's the most efficient way to answer them using Neo4j.
Thank's. WilliamLyon Thank's, I visited this plugin and therefore I suggested the model like tree. But the question is: this approach is efficient? Thank you guys!

Comment: My point was that we cannot determine an efficient model without knowing things like: how is that data is going to be used, which queries will be the most common, which ones will need to be the most efficient, etc. There are many designs possible, but the right one to use depends on your actual use cases. No single design is universally suitable.

Comment: @cybersam Thank's, I understand your point. How I need performance, I thought there was some good practice for this kind of approach in Neo4j, mainly because it does not natively treat Date type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cybersam mentioned, there are a lot of ways to model the data.

As Neo4j is schemaless, this is often an advantage and sometimes the contrary when it comes to modeling.

I'll just give two cents after reading the comments :

1. Transaction are events bound to multiple accounts and have paths between them.

For retrieving the last transaction on an account, a common practice is to use linked lists

```
(account)<-[:LAST_TRANSACTION]-(transaction)<-[:PREVIOUS_TRANSACTION]-(transaction)
```

This has some advantages when you want to do pattern matching between multiple parties in your graph, however this is a heavy operation on write time when using Cypher (while you need to have a big write throughput before reaching it but I reached it in one app already), in Java it is ok.

Some documentation here : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html

2. William suggested the TimeTree plugin for managing dates and this is a good choice and I thanks him (Nb: I'm working for the company behind the product). This offers you to be able to do some additional pattern matching between the timetree and other parties in the graph. This can support a very high write throughput without any problem.

Nb: I have seen people using the TimeTree for counting events on daily, monthly, year basis. If your use case is **no more** than that, the Timetree and Neo4j will not bring you any satisfaction for such basic operations, Redis will perform obviously better.

3. Take a paper, and ask you a question about what you want to ask to your graph and draw the question as nodes and relationships, so be declarative, ask exactly WHAT you want to retrieve and not HOW. Do it 10,20,30 times and you will see, new questions will come naturally by visualising what you draw. Then Test it, try to load some data and do some queries.
4. If things are still unclear, scan your drawings and amend the question here with the set of questions you found, we'll definitely be happy to help you.

Comment: Thank's @ChristopheWillemsen. I'm starting with the tip 3. When the questions appear I'll keep posting here.